# How can I count these values?

Tags: java, string

I have a DB that usually generates a file with 3000 lines, actually I want to count the number of LAYERID(s)

My DB file is like this :

```
CREATE TRMD=GFT,LAYID=LY_00,USFGN=DISABLED;
CREATE BUTYP=ACB8T,RAAT=FALSE,GBPATH=AAP4,GTXT=12;
CREATE TRMD=GFT,LAYID=LY_00,USFGN=DISABLED;
CREATE TRMD=GFT,LAYID=LY_01,USFGN=DISABLED;
CREATE TRMD=GFT,LAYID=LY_01,USFGN=DISABLED;
CREATE TRMD=GFT,LAYID=LY_02,USFGN=DISABLED;
CREATE BUTYP=ACB9T,RAAT=TRUE,GBPATH=AAP4,GTXT=32;
CREATE TRMD=GFT,LAYID=LY_00,USFGN=DISABLED;
CREATE TRMD=GFT,LAYID=LY_01,USFGN=DISABLED;
CREATE TRMD=GFT,LAYID=LY_02,USFGN=DISABLED;
CREATE TRMD=GFT,LAYID=LY_03,USFGN=DISABLED;
CREATE TRMD=GFT,LAYID=LY_03,USFGN=DISABLED;
CREATE BUTYP=ACB2T,RAAT=TRUE,GBPATH=AAP4,GTXT=1;
CREATE TRMD=GFT,LAYID=LY_00,USFGN=DISABLED;
CREATE BUTYP=ACB8T,RAAT=FALSE,GBPATH=AAP4,GTXT=2;
CREATE TRMD=GFT,LAYID=LY_00,USFGN=DISABLED;
CREATE BUTYP=ACB8T,RAAT=TRUE,GBPATH=AAP4,GTXT=3;
```

if we just have "`LAYID=LY_00`" (like the first line) we must ignore it, but if under the "`LAYID=LY_00`" be "`LAYID=LY_01` and ..." (like the third line) we must count "`LAYID=LY_00`" and others layerids,for example in line 3 till line 6 we have 4 Layeids

```
LAYID=LY_00
LAYID=LY_01
LAYID=LY_01
LAYID=LY_02
```

So count is 4 and if we want to count all of them we have 9, As I said before, if we just have

LAYID=LY_00 simillar line 1 we ignore it.

Also I wrote this method for read line by line :

```
public void execToken(File f) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            StringTokenizer strt = new StringTokenizer(line, ";");
            while (strt.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String token = strt.nextToken();
                layerSupport(token);
            }
        }
    }
```

and, I know the below method is not true and complete yet, but it's maybe useful for you

```
public void layerSupport(String token){
        if(token.startsWith("CREATE TRMD") && !token.contains("LAYID=LY_00"))
            System.out.println(token) ;

    }
```

many thanks for your help ...

Comment: you may have to use a regex for this.

Comment: I don't get your example, how exactly do you derive the `9`? Maybe you can further explain that?

Comment: similar as @home, I also do not understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public int execToken(File f) throws Exception
{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
    String line;
    int count = 0;
    Pattern layID = Pattern.compile("LAYID=LY_\\d+");
    Matcher matcher = null;
    boolean isSingle = true;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        if(line.contains("LAYID=LY_00"))
        {
            isSingle = false;
            continue;
        }
        matcher = layID.matcher(line);
        if(matcher.find())
        {
            count++;
            if(!isSingle)
                count++;
        }

        isSingle = true;
    }
    return count;
}
```

try this.it remembers if previous line contains `LAYID=LY_00` and increments count twice in next iteration, if `LAYID=LY_<digits>` was found and isSingle is false.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this method was very impressive ;)

Answer (score 1):

Something like that:

```
public int execToken(File f) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
    int count = 0;
    String line;
    String previousLine = ""; 
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.startsWith("CREATE TRMD")) {
            if (!previousLine.isEmpty()) {
                count += (previousLine.contains("LAYID=LY_00") ? 2 : 1);
            }
            previousLine = line;
        } else {
            previousLine = "";
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

Not tested.

Comment: `previousLine` stands for the previous "CREATE TRMD" line in the file, and is reset to `""` every time we encounter another type of line.